# uilabel with outline or stroke

Tags: ios4, uilabel, iphone

I was wondering how can I create text stroke for UILabel ? is there any possible way ?
[image]

thank you ,

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface CustomLabel : UILabel {

 }

 @end

#import "CustomLabel.h"


@implementation CustomLabel

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGSize shadowOffset = self.shadowOffset;
    UIColor *textColor = self.textColor;

    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 22);

    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(c, kCGTextStroke);
    self.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [super drawTextInRect:rect];

    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(c, kCGTextFill);
    self.textColor = textColor;
    self.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    [super drawTextInRect:rect];

    self.shadowOffset = shadowOffset;
    //works fine with no warning 
}
```

now the question is how can i use this subclass with a IBOutlet label on different viewcontrollers . is it right :

```
    label = [[CustomLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 190, 190)];
```

Comment: Why don't you try creating `label` in Interface Builder and making the connections so that your app does that absolute least amount of work?

Comment: Thanks! Great idea! Still it needs to be parametrize, like the line width, color, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It may be helpful to some to add that depending on font and characters, adding:

```
CGContextSetLineJoin(c,kCGLineJoinRound);
```

can prevent artifacts from too large a stroke applied to too sharp a character.

Answer (score 0):

There is one issue with this implementation. Drawing a text with stroke has a slightly different character glyph width than drawing a text without stroke, which can produce "uncentered" results. You can fix that by adding an invisible stroke around the fill text.

You should replace:

```
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(c, kCGTextFill);
self.textColor = textColor;
self.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
[super drawTextInRect:rect];
```

with:

```
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFillStroke);
self.textColor = textColor;
[[UIColor clearColor] setStroke]; // invisible stroke
self.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
[super drawTextInRect:rect];
```

I'm not 100% sure, if that's the real deal, because I don't know if `self.textColor = textColor;` has the same effect as `[textColor setFill]`, but you get the idea.

Disclosure: I'm the developer of THLabel.

I've released a UILabel subclass a while ago, which allows an outline in text and other effects. You can find it here: https://github.com/tobihagemann/THLabel