# How to draw only the outline of a text, but not the fill itself?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-graphics

I'm drawing text in -drawRect with this method:

```
[someText drawInRect:rect withFont:font lineBreakMode:someLineBreakMode alignment:someAlignment];
```

I just want to draw the outline but not the fill!

I've found that I can set `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor` and just provide an fully transparent color. But I fear this has bad performance impact because probably it does all the heavy drawing work behind the scenes with a transparent color.

Is there a way to just disable the fill-drawing if only outline-drawing is wanted?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make UILabel display outlined text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103148/how-do-i-make-uilabel-display-outlined-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `kCGTextFillStroke`? This might work easily. To use it, just override `drawTextInRect`

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {

  CGSize shadowOffset = self.shadowOffset;
  UIColor *textColor = self.textColor;

  CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 1);
  CGContextSetLineJoin(c, kCGLineJoinRound);

  CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(c, kCGTextStroke);
  self.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  [super drawTextInRect:rect];

  CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(c, kCGTextFill);
  self.textColor = textColor;
  self.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
  [super drawTextInRect:rect];

  self.shadowOffset = shadowOffset;

}
```

EDIT: This answer also appears in a previous incarnation of this question: [How do I make UILabel display outlined text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103148/how-do-i-make-uilabel-display-outlined-text)