# Outline for UILabel text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

How do I add a black outline to my white UILabel text?

Comment: check this :http://stackoverflow.com/a/1424665/845115

Comment: @rakeshNS yes I want black border around the text of label.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option is to set the shadow, which might not be exactly what you want, but achieves a similar effect. You can manually adjust the offset:

```
UILabel *myLabel = ...;
lbl.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
lbl.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1.0);
```

Please note that you can also define this in Interface Builder for your `UILabel`.

[shadow http://i.minus.com/jbiG0jVdOxJbgh.png](http://i.minus.com/jbiG0jVdOxJbgh.png)

If this is not enough for you check out this [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20180331201751/http://www.redrobotstudios.com:80/blog/2010/04/29/create-glow-soft-shadow-text-on-iphone/) which  deals with subclassing `UILabel` to get a glow effect:

[image: glow]
<sub>(source: [redrobotstudios.com](http://www.redrobotstudios.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/glow1.png))</sub>

Comment: Doing this it this way either adds a fuzzy outline, or the stroke/outline is offset. See this link for a great solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15877054/254598

Answer (score 6):

Disclosure: I'm the developer of THLabel.

I've released a UILabel subclass a while ago, which allows an outline in text and other effects. You can find it here: https://github.com/tobihagemann/THLabel

I'm using Core Text and Core Graphics to achieve the effect.

Comment: Just installed it, works flawlessly so far, well done.

Answer (score 2):

For iOS5, the usual way is to use CoreGraphics to set fill/stroke and then render the graphics. It can be pretty tricky to get the alignment correct for all font sizes though.

I recommend looking at my solution [here](http://www.aegik.se/226/outlined-text-with-uilabel/). You can either use it straight (it has diffuse shadows as well), or simply pick out the code that does the outline. For iOS6 there is a neater (smaller) solution which works even better. Look [here](http://www.aegik.se/334/uilabel-outlines-on-ios-6/).

Comment: iOS6 is out now, could you tell us about the neater solution ? I could not figure it out.

Comment: Yes @Nuoji , I'm also interested in knowing about that iOS 6 solution.

Comment: As you've seen I've updated my reply with a link to the iOS 6 solution.

Comment: This solution is very slow fore fonts like Chalkduster

Comment: @PsychoDad - which one, iOS5 or iOS6 solution?

Comment: Only have tested on iOS 6 device

Comment: @PsychoDad so you're using the iOS6 version then? In the case of both my solutions, my complete versions of these are extremely conservative when it comes to requesting a redraw of the graphics for exactly this reason. You should never request a redraw unless the text really is updated, or this will be dead slow.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure [this](http://www.vigorouscoding.com/2012/02/custom-gradient-uilabel-with-an-outline/#comment-130) code will solve your problem.

In KSLabel.m class see this line of code

```
// Outline color
self.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

change it to

```
self.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

and you will see the black border of the text.