# view images from array's index

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, uiimageview, nsarray

i created an array that contain images, i animate them via animationImages. but now i want to view image from the array index(i want to create a for loop with count, and if my count is equal to 1 so it will view the image at index 1 from the array) and animate them. i need it becuase i want to view number from 1 to 100 and if my number is equal to 11 then i will show number 1 twich(to avoid from creating 100 image of numbers).
how can i do it?
here is my correct code:

```
//Numbers images
UIImage *numberZero = [UIImage imageNamed:@"numberZero.png"];
UIImage *numberOne = [UIImage imageNamed:@"numberOne.png"];
UIImage *numberTwo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"numberTwo.png"];
UIImage *numberThree = [UIImage imageNamed:@"numberThree.png"];
UIImage *numberFour = [UIImage imageNamed:@"numberFour.png"];
UIImage *numberFive = [UIImage imageNamed:@"numberFive.png"];
UIImage *numberSix = [UIImage imageNamed:@"numberSix.png"];
UIImage *numberSeven = [UIImage imageNamed:@"numberSeven.png"];
UIImage *numberEight = [UIImage imageNamed:@"numberEight.png"];
UIImage *numberNine = [UIImage imageNamed:@"numberNine.png"];


//add numbers uiimage to numbersArray
numbersArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:numberZero, numberOne, numberTwo, numberThree, numberFour, numberFive, numberSix, numberSeven, numberEight, numberNine, nil];


UIImageView *imgview1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 90, 240, 240)];
imgview1.animationImages = numbersArray;
imgview1.animationDuration = 2;
imgview1.animationRepeatCount=1;
[imgview1 startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:imgview1];
```

thanks!

Comment: how important is it that you want the images? if you can find a font that looks similar then you can just use a regular label and update the text.

Comment: i know but i want to create a double border to the label's text, if it is possible it will avoid me from a lot of work... is it possible??

Comment: I'm not very familiar with it, but there's a framework called Core Text  that you can check out here: <https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html>. Core Text is an advanced, low-level technology for laying out text and handling fonts. Maybe you could use that for the double border

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unsure of your question, but I gather you're trying to animate counting to 100(?) using your images as the digits. Thus,  use one `UIImageView` for each digit, all with the same animations images, and animate the different places at relative durations:

```
float onesDurations = 2;
UIImageView *onesPlace = [[UIImageView alloc] init...]; 
onesPlace.animationImages = numbersArray;
onesPlace.animationDuration = onesDurations;

UIImageView *tensPlace = [[UIImageView alloc] init...]; 
tensPlace.animationImages = numbersArray;
tensPlace.animationDuration = 10*onesDurations; // ten times as slow as ones animation

UIImageView *hundredsPlace = [[UIImageView alloc] init...]; 
hundredsPlace.animationImages = numbersArray;
hundredsPlace.animationDuration = 100*onesDurations; // 100 times as slow animation

// add them all to the view
// start their animations
```

Answer (score 0):

You could display text instead of images with a custom font. If you want to add a border or outline, then you will have to do abit more work. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103148/how-do-i-make-uilabel-display-outlined-text) explains how you can add an outline to your text.

hope this helps