# Draw UIlabel With dark shadow color

Tags: uilabel

How to draw UILabel with dark shadow color like image shown below.

Here is code which i am trying..

```
self.averageLabel.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
self.averageLabel.layer.shadowOffset= CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
self.averageLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope my suggestions will be help full to you ,

```
 self.averageLabel.bordercolor =[UIColor  whitecolor];
 self.averageLabel.layer.borderwidth=3.0;
```

Or
  once you refer this link provided below.

[How do I make UILabel display outlined text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103148/how-do-i-make-uilabel-display-outlined-text)

Comment: Your link was really helpfull.. Thanks