# Text Shadow - iOS, swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, uilabel, border

I'm trying to make shadow size a bit bigger but I can't do it.

so far:

```
findAPlace.titleLabel?.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
findAPlace.titleLabel?.layer.shouldRasterize = true
findAPlace.titleLabel?.layer.shadowRadius = 1
findAPlace.titleLabel?.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
findAPlace.titleLabel?.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red:0.07, green:0.07, blue:0.07, alpha:1.0).cgColor
```

how to scale shadow to be bigger than the text itself?

something like this.

[image: example]

Maybe with a border can be done, My text is the title of a `UIButton`!!!I expect it to be all around text of the uiButton

Comment: This seems to ba aduplicate from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103148/how-do-i-make-uilabel-display-outlined-text

Comment: i'm trying to add to button title, not to label, its different and i cant figure it out!

Comment: You need to use `yourButton.setTitle("Your title", forState: .normal)` https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton/1624018-settitle

Comment: i know, i want to customize the title text!!!

Comment: Looks like you want a font outline, not a shadow. So maybe this will help: http://mabdev.com/2016/06/09/how-to-outline-your-uilabel-uibutton/

Comment: @Dpetrov have you found a proper solution to outline the title of a UIButton? I could not find any workaround so far

Comment: can't remember what i did, i already moved on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this way to achieve the outlined text.

You have to use attributed string and use `setAttributedTitle` property of button to get required result.

**Here is the code:**

**Swift 4**

```
let strokeTextAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [
    NSAttributedStringKey.strokeColor : UIColor.red,
    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.gray,
    NSAttributedStringKey.strokeWidth : -2.0,
]

let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "text", attributes: strokeTextAttributes)
self.btnTemp.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)
```

**Swift 3**

```
let strokeTextAttributes = [
    NSStrokeColorAttributeName : UIColor.red,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.gray,
    NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : -2.0,
] as [String : Any]

let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "text", attributes: strokeTextAttributes)
self.btnTemp.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can do in this way

Actually You need to use `setTitleShadowColor` instead of `titleLabel?.layer.shadowColor`

Here is full working code

```
    let btnTemp = UIButton(type: .custom)
    btnTemp.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 200, width: 150, height: 40)
    btnTemp.setTitle("Hello", for: .normal)
    btnTemp.titleLabel?.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    btnTemp.titleLabel?.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
    btnTemp.titleLabel?.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    btnTemp.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
    btnTemp.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    btnTemp.titleLabel?.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
    btnTemp.setTitleShadowColor(UIColor(red:0.07, green:0.07, blue:0.07, alpha:1.0), for: .normal)
    self.view.addSubview(btnTemp)
```

Hope it helps

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: can i make it with border property, and how ? its not how i expect! It needs to be all around text.

Comment: @Dpetrov, do you want to shadow the background of text? like this http://imgur.com/a/MOqoA

Comment: No, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnA51.png (it's in the question)